# How to Pulse AND Step a Load in LTSPICE

Tags: simulation, ltspice

I am attempting to model a 3V3 regulator supply that will be powering things like microcontrollers and optocouplers. I have successfully modeled the regulator, now I am attempting to model the loads that it will experience to find what the maximum load will be.
Currently I am simply stepping the load to see how it responds to various "constant" loads and where it begins to drop out (see below).
[image: Existing Setup]
The issue is, in practice, this circuit is only going to be experiencing short but repeating pulses of loading, in the order of micro/milliseconds each time. So I was wondering whether there was a way of essentially pulsing the resistor value as you would a voltage source, as well as having it step through different resistor values.
I have done a quick search on the web to no avail so hoped you guys might be able to be of assistance.
One thing I am considering if this is not possible, is having a switch (transistor) controlled by a pulsed voltage source that will in-turn pulse the load seen by the regulator. But curiosity has led me to this question before opting for the aforementioned method.

Comment: Could you replace R8 with a current source and control pulse that way ?

Comment: I normally use the SW and a voltage source to control said SW to insert another resistor at a given time.

Comment: The current source is definitely the way to go here. And I would add that those two caps in parallel look quite funny, unless op set different ESR for them. If you need ESR, place a resistor in series so you don't forget it's there :)

Answer (score 3):

I recently had some pretty extensive requirements along these lines and ended up discovering four fundamental methods. For your application I think method 3 is going to be the winner, but let me outline them so you can evaluate:

**Method 1: .step**

As in your question, simple but no time domain control.

**Method 2: Switch Model**

As in [winny's](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/296767/94854) answer. The presence of the switch model in the current path complicates things.

**Method 3: Variable Parameters**

Set your resistor's resistance to an expression involving `V(netname)`, and then drive that net with a variable voltage of your choice.

[image]

Very simple to include in circuit and very powerful to control because you can use any voltage source circuit. For example, in your case you can drive `setpoint` with a pulse voltage source and a PWL voltage source to get step and pulse behaviours.

**Method 4: Behavioural Sources**

Similar to Method 3, but use a behavioural source (bi or bv) instead of a passive component.

[image]

Adds the extra feature of controlling a source rather than a sink.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the simplest solutions to doing a trainsient on the load. You can still use the .STEP command "in the background" to vary some other parameter.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: `R1` and `R2` can be skipped by setting the appropriate values in `Ron` and `Roff`, in the `.model` card. This way you eliminate one node and two elements in the circuit matrix.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Yes indeed. I just don't like it. I even place ESR of capacitors as separate resistors to give me a visual aid, but people are different.